# Analytics metrics e.g. visitBounceRate, AvgTimeOnSite NOT accessible via AdWords API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I am developing a bid management application for Google AdWords. For several internal predictions i would like to use not only the standard AdWords metrics but also some (OnPage)-Analytics metrics like visitBounceRate & AvgTimeOnSite.

Both accounts are linked properly and I can pull these data directly from AdWords using AdWords Scripts in the AdWords interface. Unfortunately i can't figure out how to pull these metrics directly via the AdWords API. There are no reports containing these metrics.

My workaround is to utilize both APIs, AdWords & Analytics, and then match the data. But that seems a little overloaded.

Is there a way to access these metrics directly via the AdWords API or is this planned for the near future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Takeshi Hagikura (AdWords API Team) stated: "Unfortunately it's not supported to pull the Analytics metrics from AdWords API and is not on the roadmap."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AdWords Scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/), they support these metrics